# Can the Windows Vista/Windows 7 "Search programs and files" text box be configured to keep history?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

By "Search programs and files" text box I'm referring to the text entry area you get when you hit the Windows key and/or click the Start button.  I'd love it if this text box could have a must recently used (MRU) history list similar to the Start/Run dialog.  Is it possible to configure this?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there isn't. I would check under the Control Panel options and browse likely settings (User, System, Appearance).